# Flutter error: "debugNeedsLayout': is not true." when using google_fonts package

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts

I have a `ListView` that lists all fonts from [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) package. I already downloaded the fonts and put them in the project in `assets/fonts/google_fonts` for offline usage. and I set `GoogleFonts.config.allowRuntimeFetching = false;`.

The problem is when I try to show them in a `ListView` like here:

```
List<String> fonts = GoogleFonts.asMap().keys.toList(growable: false);
return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text(
            fonts[index],
            style: GoogleFonts.getFont(fonts[index],
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground)),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
    },
    itemCount: fonts.length,
  );
```

Then when I scroll within the list, the texts first appear without styling, and I get this error below, and then the styles appear, and now even if I scroll again I don't get the error anymore. I tried tracing the error stack but couldn't figure out whats happening.

How to fix this error? Is there maybe a way to load the fonts on application start?

note: this error appears only if I scroll fast through the list, so it has something to do with the styles not being loaded?

The error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/painting/text_painter.dart': Failed assertion: line 954 pos 12: '!_debugNeedsLayout': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      TextPainter.getPositionForOffset (package:flutter/src/painting/text_painter.dart:954:12)
#3      RenderParagraph.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:444:52)
#4      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#6      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#7      RenderMouseRegion.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2985:18)
#8      RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:92:25)
#9      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#10     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:87:21)
#11     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#13     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#15     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#18     RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1663:22)
#19     BoxHitTestResult.addWithOutOfBandPosition (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:882:31)
#20     RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1660:19)
#21     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:558:11)
#22     RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1282:11)
#23     SliverHitTestResult.addWithAxisOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:855:31)
#24     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:219:14)
#25     RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1282:11)
#26     RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:717:24)
#27     BoxHitTestResult.addWithOutOfBandPosition (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:882:31)
#28     RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:714:33)
#29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#31     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#32     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3349:31)
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#34     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#36     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#38     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#40     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#42     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#44     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#46     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:535:18)
#47     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#49     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#50     RenderMouseRegion.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2985:18)
#51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#52     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#54     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#56     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#58     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#59     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2824:25)
#60     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#61     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2819:33)
#62     RenderFlex.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1072:12)
#63     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#65     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#67     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#68     RenderClipRRect.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1543:18)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#70     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#72     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#74     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:535:18)
#75     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#77     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#78     RenderPhysicalShape.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2018:18)
#79     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:92:25)
#80     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#81     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:87:21)
#82     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#84     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#85     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#86     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#88     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#89     RenderPhysicalModel.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1918:18)
#90     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:92:25)
#91     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#92     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:87:21)
#93     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#94     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2824:25)
#95     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#96     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2819:33)
#97     RenderStack.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:602:12)
#98     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#100    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#102    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#103    RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3349:31)
#104    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#105    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#107    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#108    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#109    _RenderFocusTrap.hitTest (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:2172:19)
#110    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#111    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#112    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#113    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#114    RenderOffstage.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3468:31)
#115    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#116    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#117    _RenderTheatre.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:771:25)
#118    BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:785:31)
#119    _RenderTheatre.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:766:33)
#120    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#121    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#122    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#123    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#124    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#125    RenderAbsorbPointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3566:17)
#126    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#127    RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
#128    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#129    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#130    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#131    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#132    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#133    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#134    RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
#135    RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2463:11)
#136    RenderView.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:185:14)
#137    RendererBinding.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:538:16)
#138    GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:352:7)
#139    GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:344:5)
#140    GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:302:7)
#141    GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:285:7)
#142    _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1442:13)
#143    _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#144    _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#145    _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#146    PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#147    _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
```

Comment: Loading fonts taking some time to render on UI. while there are 1398 font

Comment: @YeasinSheikh so how does this help answering my question?

Comment: Reducing the fontList size and a better cache system, though you might not be looking for to reduce the list.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh this is definitely not an answer to my question! I asked how to solve the error while still using all the fonts, I don't want to reduce the options to make the error go away, this is not a solution!

Comment: You might need to use pagination.

Comment: @UsamaKarim yes that might be a good way to solve it, although I still don't understand why is this error happening

Comment: Yap, I just pointed the issue,  you can increase the `cacheExtent` to produce the issue initially

Comment: looks like a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103989)